# Using rc.local to run a command on boot

Tags: linux, centos, init.d, rc.local

I am running CentOS and want to execute a command when the system is booted. Reading other posts on ServerFault the recommend file to use is `rc.local`. However, `rc.local` exists in both `/etc/` and `/etc/rc.d/`. Which file should I use, and what is the difference between the two?

Thanks.

Comment: /etc/rc.local is a symlink to /etc/rc.d/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

I believe `/etc/rc.local` is a symlink to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

Comment: Just put everything before the "exit 0" and your are good to go :) . Try to use full path of the comands like "/sbin/iptables" for example to avoid problems.